# My android app can't access my computer's localhost

Tags: android, xampp, localhost

My scenario is this I have a android app that needs to connect to my computer's localhost to access some APIs that my co-workers created. I successfully accessed my localhost through another computer's browser and my phone's browser both by the way are on the same network. The problem is that when I run my android app it can't seem to connect to my computer's localhost. I already search and read a lot of forums for answers but to no avail.

Comment: how did you try to access the localhost from the mobile?

Comment: could you post the code here and logcat errors if any

Comment: use the IP address 10.0.2.2 for localhost.

Comment: use computer's IP address in place of localhost or 127.0.0.1 if you have used....

Comment: My computer's ip address is 192.168.1.62 and my phone's ip is 192.168.1.177 both are on the same network. I can access my localhost using my phone's browser but whenever I run my app it can't seem to see my localhost even though I used the same url in accessing via the phone's browser

Comment: make sure your manifest file has the following set     
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

refer http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your phone network is on same network. It should use same WiFi connection and off your firewall of the system then access it by your system IP that should work.

Comment: Both are on the same network, turned off my computer's firewall, added correct permission on my android app. As I stated I can access my localhost using my phone's browser but when I run my android app it can't seem to see/connect to it...

Comment: How are you trying to access your webservice from phone ?

Comment: First I tried using the phone's built in browser and entered the url for the API "http://192.168.1.62/myApp/loginAPI.php" which is successful since I can see the codes. On my app I used JsonObjectRequest() and supplied the exact url as one the parameters but it returns a null value whenever I out the returned obj... By the way I just started in android development so might not understand some terms you guys might use

Comment: You cannot use exactly the same url as you posted here. You have to add 'http://' in front.

Comment: @Rafael Try to access like `http://192.168.1.62/myApp/loginAPI.php` then it should work

Comment: I already added 'http://' in my url also tried adding the port sorry if I didn't specify it earlier